# Error when posting line in Powershell for Docker ring doorbell timelapse

Tags: docker

I got a GitHub tutorial for getting a timelapse with your ring camera but don't get what I should do in the last step. It asks me to start the container by running:

```
docker run 
  -d 
  -e TOKEN="<insert token here>" 
  -v "/media/timelapse:/app/dist/target" 
  --restart unless-stopped 
  wictorwilen/ring-timelapse
```

But after changing the token key and path files I get this error message in Powershell:

```
At line:5 char:5
+   --restart unless-stopped
+     ~
Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At line:5 char:5
+   --restart unless-stopped
+     ~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'restart' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

The link to the GitHub document is [here](https://github.com/wictorwilen/ring-timelapse).

I already installed Node.js, the ring-client-api and npx so I am pretty confused about this error.